# Does Enumerable.OrderBy order complete list if only first element is requested

Tags: performance, linq

If a sequence is ordered. And you only ask for the first element of the ordered sequence. Is Orderby smart enough not to order the complete sequence?

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> myItems = ...
MyClass maxItem = myItems.OrderBy(item => item.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

So if the first element is asked, only the item with the minimum value is ordered as first element of the sequence. When the next element is asked, the item with the minimum value of the remaining sequence is ordered etc.

Or is the complete sequence completely ordered if you only want the first element?

**Addition**

Apparently the question is unclear. Let's give an example.

The Sort function could do the following:

- Create a linked list containing all the elements
- as long as the linked list contains element:

  - Take the first element of the linked list as the smallest
  - scan the rest of the linked list once to find any smaller elements
  - remove the smallest element from the linked list
  - yield return the smallest element

Code:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Sort<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));

    IComparer<TKey> comparer = Comparer<TKey>.Default;

    // create a linkedList with keyValuePairs of TKey and TSource
    var keyValuePairs = source
        .Select(source => new KeyValuePair<TKey, TSource>(keySelector(source), source);
    var itemsToSort = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<Tkey, TSource>>(keyValuePairs);

    while (itemsToSort.Any())
    {   // there are still items in the list
        // select the first element as the smallest one
        var smallest = itemsToSort.First();

        // scan the rest of the linkedList to find the smallest one
        foreach (var element in itemsToSort.Skip(1))
        {
           if (comparer.Compare(element.Key, smallest.Key) < 1)
        {   // element.Key is smaller than smallest.Key: element becomes the smallest:
            smallest = element;
        }
    }

    // remove the smallest element from the linked list and return the value:
    itemsToSort.Remove(smallestElement);
    yield return smallestElement.Value;
}
```

Suppose I have a sequence of integers.

```
Suppose I have the following sequence of integers:

{4, 8, 3, 1, 7}
```

At the first iteration the iterator internally creates a linked list of key/value pairs and assigns the first element of the list as smallest

```
Linked List =  4 - 8 - 3 - 1 - 7
Smallest = 4
```

The linked list is scanned once to see if there is a smaller one.

```
Linked List =  4 - 8 - 3 - 1 - 7
Smallest = 1
```

The smallest is removed from the linked list and yield return:

```
Linked List =  4 - 8 - 3 - 7
return 1
```

The second iteration the same is done with the shorter linked list

```
Linked List =  4 - 8 - 3 - 7
smallest = 4
```

Again the linked list is scanned once to find the smallest one

```
Linked List =  4 - 8 - 3 - 7
smallest = 3
```

Remove the smallest from the linked list and return the smallest

```
Linked List =  4 - 8 -  7
return 3
```

It's easy to see that if you only ask for first element in the sorted list, the list is scanned only once. Every iteration the list to scan becomes smaller.

**Back to my original question:**

I understand that if you only want the first element, you have to scan the list at least once. If you don't ask for a second element, the rest of the list is not ordered.

Is the sort that is used by Enumerable.OrderBy thus smart that if doesn't sort the remainder of the list if you only ask for the firs ordered item?

Comment: No, it's not. How can it know that the list is in order without iterating through the entire list?

Comment: Your question is unclear. How do you suppose `OrderBy` finds the minimum element without traversing the entire `IEnumerable`?

Comment: If you had read the top answer you would know that ___the__ sort that is used by Enumerable.OrderBy_ does not exist. There are many.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you look at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,618) and follow the [classes](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,3eaf3f03262e9ab6) you will see that all keys will be computed and then a quick sort algorithm will sort the index table according to the keys.

So the sequence is read once, all the keys are computed, then an index is sorted according to the keys and then you get your first output.

Comment: The source for .NET Core's version at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/First.cs#L57 and https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/OrderedEnumerable.cs#L246 shows how quick sort isn't used for the combination `OrderBy(…).FirstOrDefault(…)` in that version.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the version.

In the framework versions (4.0, 4.5, etc.) then:

1. The entire source is loaded into a buffer.
2. Produce a map of keys (so that they key production is only once per element).
3. A map of integers is produced and then sorted according to those keys (using a map means swap operations have cheaper copies if the source elements are large value types).
4. The `FirstOrDefault` attempts to obtain the first item according to this mapping by using `MoveNext` and `Current` on the resulting object. Either it finds one, or (if the buffer is empty because the source was empty) returns `default(TSource)`.

In .NET Core, then:

1. The `FirstOrDefault` operation on the `IOrderedEnumerable` scans through the source. If there are no elements it returns `default(TSource)` otherwise it holds onto the first element found and the key produced by the key generator and compares it with all subsequent, replacing that held-onto value and key with the next found if the next found compares as lower than the current value.
2. The held-onto value will be the same element as the Framework version would have found by first sorting, so it is returned.

This means that in the Framework version `myItems.OrderBy(item => item.Id).FirstOrDefault()` is `O(n log n)` time complexity (worse case `O(n²)`) and `O(n)` space complexity, but in the .NET Core version it is `O(n)` time complexity and `O(1)` space complexity.

The main difference here is that in .NET Core `FirstOrDefault()` has knowledge of how the results of `OrderBy` (and `ThenBy` etc.) differ from other possible sources and has code to handle it*, while in the framework version it does not.

Both scan the entire sequence (you can't know the last element in `myItems` isn't the first by the sorting rules until you've examined it) but they differ in the mechanism and efficiency after that point.

> When the next element is asked, the item with the minimum value of the remaining sequence is ordered etc.

If the next element is asked, then not only would any sorting be done again, but it would **have** to be done again as the contents of `myItems` could have change in the meantime.

If you were trying to obtain it with `myItems.OrderBy(item => item.Id).ElementAtOrDefault(i)` then the framework version would find the element by first doing a sort (`O(n log n)`) and then a scan (`O(n)` relative to `i`) while the .NET Core version would find it with a quickselect (`O(n)` though the constant factors are bigger than for `FirstOrDefault()` and can be as high as `O(n²)` in the same cases that sorting is, so its a slower `O(n)` than with that (it's smart enough to turn `ElementAtOrDefault(0)` into `FirstOrDefault()` for that reason). Both versions also use space complexity of `O(n)` (unless .NET Core can turn it into `FirstOrDefault()`).

If you were finding the first few values with `myItems.OrderBy(item => item.Id).Take(k)` then the Framework version would again do a sort (`O(n log n)`) and the put a limit on the subsequent enumeration of the results so that it stopped returning elements after `k` were obtained. The .NET Core version would do a partial sort, not bothering to sort elements it realised were always going to come after the portion taken, which is `O(n + k log k)` time complexity. .NET Core would also do a single partial sort for combinations of `Take` and `Skip` reducing the amount of sorting necessary further.

In theory the sorting of just `OrderBy(cmp)` could be lazier as per:

1. Load the elements into the buffer.
2. Do a sort, probably favouring the "left" partition as partitioning is happening.
3. `yield` elements as soon as it is found that they are the next to enumerate.

This would improve time-to-first-result (low time-to-first-result is often a nice feature of other Linq operations), and particularly benefit consumers who may stop working on the result part way through. However it adds extra constant costs to the sorting operation and either prevents picking the next partition to work on in such a way as to reduce the amount of recursion (an important optimisation of partition-based sorting) or else would often not actually yield anything until near the end anyway (making the exercise rather pointless). It would also make the sorting much more complicated. While I experimented with this approach the pay-offs to some cases didn't justify the costs to others, especially as it seemed likely to hurt more people than it benefited.

*Strictly speaking, the results of several linq operations have knowledge of how to find the first element in a way that is optimised for each of them, and `FirstOrDefault()` knows how to detect any of those cases.

Comment: Great to know, I never looked through the Core versions.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Maybe one day some of those optimisations will be ported by into the framework. It's listed as for consideration for that.

Answer (score 2):

> If a sequence is ordered ...

That is fine but not a property of IEnumerable so OrderBy can never 'know' this directly.

There are precedents for this though,  `Count()` will check at runtime if its `IEnumerable<> source` is actually pointing at a List and then take a shortcut to the Count property.

Likewise, OrderBy could look to see if it's called on a SortedList or something but there is no clear marker interface and those collections are used far too infrequently to make this worth the effort.

There are other ways to optimize this, `.OrderBy().First()` could conceivably map to a `.Min()` but again, nobody has bothered <strike>till now</strike> as far as I knew. See Jon's answer.

Comment: I bothered in 2015, so it does map to a form of `.Min()`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. How can it know that the list is in order without iterating through the entire list?

Here's a simple test:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(OrderedEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x).First());
}

public IEnumerable<int> OrderedEnumerable()
{
    Console.WriteLine(1);
    yield return 1;
    Console.WriteLine(2);
    yield return 2;
    Console.WriteLine(3);
    yield return 3;
}
```

This, as expected, outputs:

```
1
2
3
1
```

Comment: This shows that the collection is fully _enumerated_ but it says nothing about the Sorting applied.

Comment: There are 2 actions in scope here: fetching the results and sorting them. You only talk about the first, the questions is about the second.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I've included the `.OrderBy(x => x)` in my code. Isn't that the ordering part?

Comment: Yes, but there's no logical need to actually sort the sequence to just find the first element. Whether that's happening or not isn't reflected by your code, which gives the same results on framework (which does sort the sequence) and Core (which does not).